# Disk I/O misalignment (I/O unaligned) issue ... who is to blame?

Tags: linux, kernel, hard-disk, disk, database

If an application, such as a database, is using the OS for writing/reading (that is, it is not directly writing to disk, i.e not using DIRECT IO or such) ... who would be to blame for I/O misalignment? Is this an OS issue? Or the application is at fault here?

Answer (score 1):

Unaligned I/O happens whenever the logical blocks (of the file or file-system) do not match the physical blocks (of the disk). So whoever partitioned the drive is to blame. In case further abstraction layers are introduced (i.e. LVM or virtualisation), there are more opportunities for misalignment. [This article](https://kb.netapp.com/app/answers/answer_view/a_id/1001578/~/what-is-an-unaligned-i%2Fo%3F-) illustrates the problem with some nice graphics (not copied due to copyright).